# I want to display a parabola defined by a line and a focus point but I don't get what is expected.

Tags: algorithms, conic-sections, curves

So I want to get the equation of the parabola from a line equation and a focus point. The line is defined by 2 points ***(x1,y1); (x2,y2)*** on a plane. and the focus point ***(fx,fy)*** is another point on the plane. The line equation look like this:

`y=m*x+b`
`m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`
`b = y1 - m*x1`

Then the equation of the parabola looks like this:

`y = ((x - fx)^2+fy^2-(m*x+b)^2)/(2*(fy-(m*x+b)));`

After these calculations I rotate the parabola equation (the points I got) with the angle of:
`angle = (tan(slope) * 180) /  PI;`

With this kind of calculation I got something like this: (the first one is okay but than I don't know what I got)
http://i.giphy.com/3oEdv3mt7fQPvVqxMY.gif

Here is another gif: http://i.giphy.com/3oEduKBNwV2A6VWy64.gif

I don't know why I got something like this. This is not what I expected.
What is wrong with my calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If I well understand you have the directrix of the parabola $d$ with equation:
$$
mx-y+(y_1-mx_1)=0 \qquad m=\dfrac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}
$$
and the focus $F=(F_x,F_y)$
so the parabola is, by definition, the locus of points $ P= (x,y)$ such that:
$$
\overline{Pd}=\overline{PF}
$$
and, using:
$$
\overline{Pd}= \dfrac{|mx-y+(y_1-mx_1)|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}
$$

$$
\overline{PF}=\sqrt{(x-F_x)^2+(y-F_y)^2}
$$
and squaring, you have the equation of the parabola that has as symmetry axis the straight line orthogonal to the directrix and passing thorough the focus.